# what is the correct format for calling a db in access, with a 'folder with spaces'?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

```
Public connstring As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\blablabla\Document\Visual Studio 2013\Project\rentalsystem\rental_db.accdb"
```

i placed this line of code under a module so i wont have to call it everytime. and this is the code that the code above is connected to...

```
Public Sub loadLVusers()
    LVusers.Items.Clear()
    Dim sqlcode As String = "select id_code, user_lastname, user_firstname, user_midname, user_username, user_password, user_email, user_privilege from tblUsers"
    Dim sqlcomd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlcode)
    sqlcomd.Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstring)
    sqlcomd.Connection.Open()
    Dim DA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcomd)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS, "Pi")
    If DS.Tables("Pi").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Ic(100) As String
        For r = 0 To DS.Tables("Pi").Rows.Count - 1
            For c = 0 To DS.Tables("Pi").Columns.Count - 1
                Ic(c) = DS.Tables("Pi").Rows(r)(c).ToString
            Next
            Dim LVI As New ListViewItem(Ic)
            LVusers.Items.Add(LVI)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

now when the form/window that it is attached to loads, the form/window does not open. and then it highlights

```
sqlcomd.Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstring)
```

so im guessing that has something to do with the file path format

Comment: VS will do more than just highlight it, it should give an explanation or error msg.  Hardcoding the path like that will only work on that machine for that user though.

Comment: when i hover over the circle before the highlight, it says, "At createuser.vb, line 20 character 9 (createUser.loadLVusers()', line 5... and yes, i would like to let it work only in my laptop.. since this is what i will be using to present it.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing your path with quotes? Double quotes (`""`) will be escaped in VB strings, so it'd look like:
`Public connstring As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = ""C:\Users\blablabla\Document\Visual Studio 2013\Project\rentalsystem\rental_db.accdb"""`